# Magento - Upgraded from 1.5 to 1.7 and getting an error in custom theme

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

After upgrading to 1.7 (all on a dev server thankfully!) I am getting the following error logs for the clients custom theme:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:93:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesAndChildrenMenuHtml(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:3806:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/p365_mydomain/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml(17): Varien_Object->__call('renderCategorie...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/p365_mydomain/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml(17): Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation->renderCategoriesAndChildrenMenuHtml()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/p365_s...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/p365_mydomain/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(34): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/p365_s...')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#19 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#20 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:22:"mydomain_store_view";}
```

Theme is working fine on a 1.5 installation, but as the theme was made by someone else (and they installed the old version, I cannot be certain they didn't tinker with any core code etc

Googling found results for "Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesMenuHtml" but not "renderCategoriesAndChildrenMenuHtml". I thought it may have been a custom function, but I found it in the core code. Totally stumped on this one!

Comment: "I cannot be certain they didn't tinker with any core code" Then never ever should have done the upgrade by yourself. This question is much too localized. You should start debugging by disabling any custom designs and installed extensions. Check if the Magento installation works – if yes re-enable each extension and template file one by one. No one here on SO could know what happened on your installation.

Comment: Whilst I appreciated your concern, I had no choice. The 1.7 installation is fresh on a development server. I copied across the custom theme, and it doesn't work. The default theme works, and so does a theme I made myself. The issue clearly lies with "renderCategoriesAndChildrenMenuHtml" but I don't know why it isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default theme of Magento 1.5.0.0 calls the `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` and block contains only the function `renderCategoriesMenuHtml`. In your case, or someone corrected the core files, or a module that rewrites the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`.

One possible solution is to replace  function `renderCategoriesAndChildrenMenuHtml` to `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` in file `app/design/frontend/p365_mydomain/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml` or use default template for navigation/left with code:

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```